# python subprocess output on nohup

Tags: python, subprocess, output, nohup

Trying to monitor the available physical disc space of a remote machine using a python script, which executes the `df -h .` command using subprocess.popen.

```
import subprocess
import time
command = 'ssh remoteserver "df -h ."'
while True:
    proc = subprocess.Popen(command,shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    output,err=proc.communicate()
    print output
    print err
    time.sleep(60)
```

The script runs fine and prints the output to the terminal when run from command line

`$> python2.7 script.py`

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
remoteserver:/home/user
                      555G  447G  109G  81% /home
```

The scripts does not produce any output or seems to be blocking when the script is started with nohup command.

`$> nohup python2.7 script.py &`

Would like the script to work and fetch the disc space of remote machine using the above script when started in `nohup`.

Comment: why don't use bash script? isn't it better for such tasks?

Comment: The above code is part of script which does few other things and had to be done in python.

Comment: `nohup` probably redirects the output to a file (`nohup.out`)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure of the underlying issue here, but when you invoke NOHUP in the shell, it's disconnected some of the STDIN/STDOUT from the terminal process, which I suspect it causing some of this interactions you're seeing.

Given that you're doing this from a remote machine, I'd actually recommend you look at using something like [Fabric](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.8/) as a library to do what you're after. It's pretty straightforward, and does most of the handling of terminal sessions as well as closing things down nicely for you when you're complete.

something like:

```
from fabric import api
from fabric.api import env
import fabric

env.host_string = '%s@%s' % (username, remote_host)
env.disable_known_hosts = True
env.password = password
fabric.state.output['stdout'] = False
fabric.state.output['stderr'] = False

results = api.run('df -h')
```

Answer (score 0):

You might try sending stdin=subprocess.PIPE to the subprocess command, then calling proc.stdin.close() on the next line, before the communicate() call. Or you can try changing the command to 'ssh remoteserver "df -h ." </dev/null'. Others report using FNULL = open(os.devnull, 'r') and passing in FNULL to the stdin= argument, but I'm not sure if you need to call FNULL.close() after or not.

SSH is most likely waiting for input for some reason when it is run from nohup. Perhaps it is unable to authenticate in the nohup environment and is asking for password input?

To make sure SSH is not waiting for input, try adding -o "BatchMode yes" to the ssh command and see if there are some clues in the output/error from the subprocess communicate call.